# React Native Expo StackNavigator overlaps Notification bar

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, create-react-native-app

I am trying to implement navigation bar for my React Native Expo app. Here is a problem:

[image]

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^18.0.3",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.45.1",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
}
```

I don't know where and how I can set up styles for this component to make it not overlap with notifications bar. I tried to set `marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight` for my root View but it didn't work. It applied the margin on the View but not on the navigation bar.

My App:

```
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Home from './app/screens/Home';

export default App = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home }
})
```

Home:

```
export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();  
        // <...>
    }

    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Welcome'
    };

    // <...>
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you wrap your entire app in a `View` with a top margin, it will work.

Example: https://snack.expo.io/r1gb9TGH-

In the future, we're going to build this into react-navigation so it happens for you automatically.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StatusBar, View} from 'react-native'
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Home from './app/screens/Home';

const RootNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home }
})

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight }}>
        <RootNavigator />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: **Exactly what I was looking for!**

Answer (score 3):

add this line to `app.json` file

```
"translucent": false
```

in `"androidStatusBar"`

like this:

```
"androidStatusBar": {
  "barStyle": "light-content",
  "backgroundColor": "#3a81fd",
  "hidden": false,
  "translucent": false
},
```

read more in : [Configuring StatusBar Docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/configuring-statusbar/?redirected#translucent)

Comment: this is a better solution for recent versions of expo

Comment: how about iOS status bar?