# Margin Top for Header Bar in React Native Navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm new in React Native. I'm using React-Navigation. But, on my device has problem with header navigation. This overlay by status bar like this.

[image]

This issue occur both on my code and from React Navigation showcase example. How to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native Expo StackNavigator overlaps Notification bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45044941/react-native-expo-stacknavigator-overlaps-notification-bar)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelCheng. It's duplicated

Answer (score 17):

You are using Expo, so this behavior is normal.

```
static navigationOptions = {
  title: "Welcome",
  headerStyle: { marginTop: 24 },
}
```

You can define your header like this.

**Edit about a year later:**

With Expo, you can now use this:

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants'

static navigationOptions = {
  title: "Welcome",
  headerStyle: { marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight },
}
```

Install it with `expo install expo-constants`

More informations [here in the expo doc](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v37.0.0/sdk/constants/)

Comment: This doesn't work as well on iOS. [Accepted answer to the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45045132/383414) works better on both platforms i.e. `marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight`

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier According to the [React Native site](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar.html#constants) `currentHeight (Android only) The height of the status bar`. So that solution doesn't seem to be working on iOS.

Comment: @CharlieFish RN changes so quickly, but when I made that comment, I was developing an Expo app on an iPhone 4c and Android Nexus 5 and got a better experience with the duplicate as said. But this is an every-flowing technology we are working on for better or worse.

Comment: for Ios use <SafeAreaView>

Comment: `import Constants from 'expo-constants'`

Answer (score 9):

I found this useful when running in the same problem

```
export default StackNavigator({
    LoginScreen: { screen: Login.component }
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'LoginScreen',
    headerMode: 'none' // <------------- This line
})
```

Just add headerMode: 'none' in the configuration object

Hope this helps

By the way Credit goes to [This Link](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2150#issuecomment-392613359)

Answer (score 5):

This should do what you want.

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Platform
} from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

const App = () => (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        // Your content with margin for statusBar goes here
    </View>
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : Constants.statusBarHeight
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case the **`StatusBar`** component cause this problem.

set `translucent` props to *`false`*

```
<StatusBar
        animated={true}
        backgroundColor={Styles.statusBar.color}
        barStyle={barStyle}
        hidden={false}
        networkActivityIndicatorVisible={true}
        showHideTransition="fade"
        translucent={false} // <----------------- add false to translucent
      />
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using expo, try to set the navigation options like this

```
navigationOptions:{
  headerStyle:{
    marginTop: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 0 : Expo.Constants.statusBarHeight }
  }
}
```

With this the padding will only take affect in android platform.
For more info you can visit [link.](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2147)

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was as simple as include the property "***headerStatusBarHeight***" with the value I wanted.

```js
const  defaultHeaderConfig = {
    headerStatusBarHeight: 20,
    headerTintColor: "white",
    headerStyle:{
        backgroundColor: "blue"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Expo,you can use   `Platform` from `expo core` so :

```
import { Constants } from "expo";
import { Platform } from "expo-core"; //inside of Platfrom from 'react-native'
```

after that create an stylesheet:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
   marginTop: Platform.OS === "ios" ? 0 : Constants.statusBarHeight
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With Expo, you could use Constants:

```js
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight
  },
});
```

You can also use the StatusBar component from ReactNative:

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight
  },
});
```